# How can I count how many times each of the names in a names list is repeated?

Tags: algorithm, logic, pseudocode

I am trying to solve algorithm problem in pseint pseudocode program, the problem is as follows:

How can I count how many times each of the names in a names list is repeated? Does anyone have any idea how it could be done?

I know how to do it for 1 single value(as long as I know it), but I can't identify how I could adapt this for what I'm looking for

Comment: could you add the method you know for  1 single single value? since you are looking to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIVIDE ET IMPERA your problem :)

1. find the distinct names in your list
2. foreach element of the previous step, count how many times it is in your list.

Find the distinct name in your list:

```
//create a new array and suppose it has as many elements as the given input:
let ris = new array[input.length]

//define an index for this array.
let k = 0
//in the rest of the algorithm let always k be the actual length of ris and the next possible index to use

//let's start iterating over the input list
for (i = 0; i<input.length; i++) {
    //let's check if input[i] it's already present in ris
    //we can look just for the first k elements
    let addCurrentName = true
    for (j = 0; j<k; j++) {
        if (input[i] == ris[j]) addCurrentName = false;
    }
    if (addCurrentName) {
         //we go inside this if only if in the previous search we found nothing
         ris[k] = input[i];
         k++;
    }
}

//now the first k positions of ris contain the distinct values of input

let ris2 = new array[k] //now we are sizing the result exactly
for (i = 0; i<k; i++) {
    ris2[i] = ris[i] //we are just creating the result of the right dimension and copying values into it
}

return ris2;
```

You said you already know how to count how many times an element is in an array, so I'll leave the rest to you, you just have to do it for all the distinct values.

Comment: thanks, the example helped me better understand what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a idea about this.

First you take an element of list and iterate about list searching an element equal

Second when an element match then count and when arrive the end of list, so remove this elements and start again

So at the end you will have counted all the elements on the list.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me to understand better, finally I took the path of creating an array (ArrayB) based on the search of what elements are different in the initial list (ArrayA), and later assign another row in the array (ArrayB) where I assign the value of how many times it was repeated

Answer (score 0):

I could not follow either of the previous answers to this question of how to count how many times a unique name appears in a column where names are repeated.

[Although this broadly is the same problem as that originally stated by the OP, a bot has flagged this as unclear. So to be clear, for example, you have a column thus:

John

Jack

Mary

Jack

John

John

John

You want to return a result:

John 4

Jack 2

Mary 1

This is what is meant by "count how many times a unique name appears in a column where names are repeated". Each name is followed by the frequency of its occurrence. I hope the bot gets it this time.]

I found a simpler solution than those above, here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/605190-count-the-number-of-times-a-value-appears-in-a-column-using-ms-access
which depends on adding a column to a simple query design.

It certainly worked for me.

Here is a screenshot of the original post:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).